# How to make these operations occur faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, precision-and-accuracy

How can I get this section of the code to solve this integration faster. I have rather large values but I don't need it to be too specific. However if I lower the precision it says the integration is 0. The function is only in a very small section of the x values according to the 3d plot. However if I analyze the smaller section it still takes a considerable amount of time. Any help is appreciated

```
timewj2 = AbsoluteTiming[
   Wjlambda5 = (1/8.952*10^8)*
      NIntegrate[
       Dot[Re[{0, -8.952*10^8*(15.675459922348419449)*(((-8.\
9652950534407867999303353030387276032035253437793*10^768 - 
                   2.1141452007443239580927869423477693294460547800052\
7*10^769*I)*
                 BesselJ[
                  1, (75062.4870217452581789128 + 
                    75062.4983440564559965704*I )*
                   x] + (2.1141452007443239580927869423477693294*10^\
769 - 8.965295053440786799930335303038727603*10^768*I)*
                 BesselY[
                  1, (75062.4870217452581789128 + 
                    75062.4983440564559965704*I )*x])*
              Exp[I*(1)*(41.2281675906100480252)*s]), 0}], 
         Re[{0, -8.952*10^8*(15.675459922348419449)*(((-8.\
9652950534407867999303353030387276032035253437793*10^768 - 
                   2.1141452007443239580927869423477693294460547800052\
7*10^769*I)*
                 BesselJ[
                  1, (75062.4870217452581789128 + 
                    75062.4983440564559965704*I )*
                   x] + (2.1141452007443239580927869423477693294*10^\
769 - 8.965295053440786799930335303038727603*10^768*I)*
                 BesselY[
                  1, (75062.4870217452581789128 + 
                    75062.4983440564559965704*I )*x])*
              Exp[I*(1)*(41.2281675906100480252)*s]), 0}]]*
        x, {x, (0.02357124714249428777766010023597686995), \
(0.04022197675031113473009371147375231401)}, {s, 
        0, (0.15240030480060962059241091992589645088)}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> (2000 - 1), MaxPoints -> 80];
   ];
Print["Time Wj5 (s) = ", N[timewj2[[1]],10]];
```

EDIT:
Like This?

```
prec = 100;
σ5 = SetPrecision[500*(1.492*^6), prec];
vs5 = SetPrecision[15.675459, prec];
γ5 = SetPrecision[75062.487021745, prec];
e = SetPrecision[-8.965295053440786799*10^768 - 
    2.1141452007443239588*10^769*I, prec];
j = SetPrecision[
   2.1141452007443239580927*10^769 - 8.96529505344078679*10^768*I, 
   prec];
mm = SetPrecision[1, prec];
k = SetPrecision[41.2281675, prec];
r45 = SetPrecision[0.02357124714249428777766010, prec];
r56 = SetPrecision[0.0402219767503111347300937114, prec];
lam = SetPrecision[.1524, prec];
timewj2 = AbsoluteTiming[
   Wjl5 = (1/σ5)*
      NIntegrate[
       Dot[
         Re[{0, -σ5* vs5*((e*BesselJ[1, γ5*x] + j*BesselY[1, γ5*x])*Exp[I*mm*k*s]), 0}], 
         Re[{0, -σ5* vs5*((e*BesselJ[1, γ5*x] + j*BesselY[1, γ5*x])*Exp[I*mm*k*s]), 0}]
         ]*x, 
       {x, r45, r56}, 
       {s, 0, lam}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> prec - 1, 
       MaxPoints -> 80
       ];
   ];
Wjl5
Print["Time Wj5 (s) = ", N[timewj2, prec2]];
```

But my output is still wrong its getting 1.02*10^1542 and the answer is close to 0 but not 0.

Comment: You seem to mixing machine arithmetic with arbitrary precision arithmetic. That never works well. I suggest expressing all quantities at a modest specific precision and working with that. I also suggest exercising patience. Difficult computations often take some time.

Comment: This is the shortest version of the numerical equivalent i could find. I set the precision of all calculations using SetPrecision and right now it is at 2000. The imaginary numbers being multiplied by the bessel function are from a resulting simultaneous equation solve that requires that level of precision. Furthermore the 3d plot will not show an accurate version unless set to a precision of say 1500. This is just one equation needed to solve for my calculations but it takes up the most time. All the other equations are done in 14 seconds or so. This one is 11405.1. Any way I can chip it down

Comment: When you include machine numbers like 8.952*10^8 in you code, then all computations involving that number in any way are done at machine precision, what you set with `SetPrecision` notwithstanding. I advise doing what I suggested in my 1st comment: re-expressing **all** the arithmetic quantities at a modest precision, say 20, and working strictly at that precision in your calculations. Also, I don't know what you are referring to when you mention "3rd plot". You show no plots. Further, plotting doesn't require high precision; it's always done at machine precision.

Comment: I completely second what m_goldber said about precision. I also observed that several of your number seem to occur multiple times. Things would become much more readible and easier to work with if you assigned multiply occuring constants as values to variables and if you would you these variables. Your code is a big mess at the moment and it is hard to figure out the structure of the integrand.

Comment: Is this closer to what you mean?

Comment: Ah, much better! Btw.: How accurate are `k` and `lam` really? I get that `k/lam` equals `85.94193388664871 Pi` could it be by any chance that it you equal `86 Pi`?

Comment: Moreover I observe that the integrand can be brought into the form $f_1(x) \cdot g_1(s) + f_2(x) \cdot g_2(s) $, so for the integral, we obtain $(\int f_1 (x) \, \mathrm{d} x) \, (\int g_1 (s) \, \mathrm{d} s) + (\int f_2 (x) \, \mathrm{d} x) \, (\int g_2 (s) \, \mathrm{d} s) $. And the 1D-integrals should be much easier to compute.

Comment: Also, all the constants, in particular the oversized ones, should be pulled in front of the integrals. And the integrals over `s` can be computed analytically (by using `Integrate` on the purely sympolical integrands and by numerizing afterwards), because they involve only trigonometric functions.

Comment: lam is in meters its about 6in/39.37 which is about .1524, k = 2*pi/lam.

Comment: I am not very smart when it comes to math. I work better with examples. I don't have a full understanding of how you are converting it into a 1d problem.

Comment: `Dot[Re[{0,-σ5*vs5*((e*BesselJ[1,γ5*x]+j*BesselY[1,γ5*x])*Exp[I*mm*k*s]),0}],
 Re[{0,-σ5*vs5*((e*BesselJ[1,γ5*x]+j*BesselY[1,γ5*x])*Exp[I*mm*k*s]),0}]]*x` == `x*Re[-σ5*vs5*((e*BesselJ[1,γ5*x]+j*BesselY[1,γ5*x])*Exp[I*mm*k*s])]^2` and that might make your code smaller and a little faster. Check to make certain this is correct.

Comment: Compare `SetPrecision[-8.965295053440786799*10^768-2.1141452007443239588*10^769*I,prec]` and `-8.965295053440786799\`100*10^768-2.1141452007443239588\`100*10^769*I` and see they are not the same. You might also write `j=e*I` to slightly simplify your code.

Comment: @Rookey you have a typo in a code, must be` \[Gamma]5 = 75062.4870217452581789128 + 75062.4983440564559965704*I`.

Answer (score 1):

We introduce the notation

```
f = a*BesselJ[1, \[Gamma]5*x] + b*BesselY[1, \[Gamma]5*x];
g = Exp[I*k*s];
```

then the required integral is

```
Wjl5 = (1/\[Sigma]5)*
      NIntegrate[
       Dot[Re[{0, f*g, 0}], Re[{0, f*g, 0}]]*x, {x, r45, r56}, {s, 0, 
        lam}];
```

The multiplication operation `Dot` can be performed,

```
Wjl5 = (1/\[Sigma]5)*
          NIntegrate[
           Re[f*g]^2*x, {x, r45, r56}, {s, 0, 
            lam}];
```

The integral over `s` is calculated analytically using `Re[fg]^2*x = (Re[f]*Cos[k*s] - Im[f]*Sin[k*s])^2*x`, we have

```
Integrate[(Re[f]*Cos[k*s] - Im[f]*Sin[k*s])^2, {s, 0, lam}]

(*Out[]= (4 f k lam Conjugate[f] - 
 8 Im[f] Re[f] Sin[k lam]^2 + (f^2 + Conjugate[f]^2) Sin[
   2 k lam])/(8 k)*)
```

define the parameters

```
\[Sigma]5 = 500*(1.492*^6);
vs5 = 15.675459;
\[Gamma]5 = 75062.4870217452581789128 + 75062.4983440564559965704*I;
e = -8.965295053440786799*10^768 - 2.1141452007443239588*10^769*I;
j = 2.1141452007443239580927*10^769 - 8.96529505344078679*10^768*I;
mm = 1;
k = 41.2281675;
r45 = 0.02357124714249428777766010;
r56 = 0.0402219767503111347300937114;
lam = .1524;
a = -\[Sigma]5*vs5*e;
b = -\[Sigma]5*vs5*j;
```

finally calculate the integral

```
With[{f = 
    a*BesselJ[1, \[Gamma]5*x] + b*BesselY[1, \[Gamma]5*x]}, 
  NIntegrate[(
    4 f k lam Conjugate[f] - 
     8 Im[f] Re[f] Sin[k lam]^2 + (f^2 + Conjugate[f]^2) Sin[
       2 k lam])/(8 k)*x, {x, r45, r56}, 
   Method -> "MonteCarlo"]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*During evaluation of In[]:= NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 0. +0. I and 0.` for the integral and error estimates.*)

Out[]= {5.69314, 0. + 0. I}
```